# How to use ZXing Barcode Scanner in a Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, zxing, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to figure out how use to use [ZXing Barcode Scanner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile/) nuget package in a simple Xamarin Forms application.

I'm trying to have a large area of my form show what my camera is seeing .. and if it scan's something.. then stop scanning and goto the next Page.

All the examples basically show this:

```
buttonScan.Click += (sender, e) => {

    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var result = await scanner.Scan();

    if (result != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
};
```

but I don't understand what the actual view/control/widget which gets displayed onto the actual page, is? Like a big square with the camera contents getting displayed etc.

What is the trick to drop a control onto the page .. which I can then wire up to scan whatever the camera is 'seeing' .. and hopefully it will 'read' the barcode or qrcode?

Comment: I believe you need to use DI to inject the behavior into your Forms app from each platform specific project.  The package is not PCL.  See: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31119/bar-code-reader-in-xamarin-form-pcl-project

Comment: According to this ZXing.Net.Mobile is PCL compatible  https://github.com/aritchie/barcodes

Comment: Complete working example for android here .  Just pull it - https://github.com/jhealy/xammutts/tree/master/ZXingPlaySLN/ZXingPlay